# Студия перестала работать с дробными числами

Tags: visual-studio

Было 2 проекта, которые отлично работали. В одном была строка типа:

```
string text = "3.14";
double d = Convert.ToDouble(text);
```

Во втором:

```
double d = 3.75;
string text = $"bla bla {d} bla"
```

После переустановки винды и студии, на этих строках проги просто стопятся, даже без ошибки, будто там написано `await Task.Delay(99999999)`. При этом, если написать `string text = $"bla bla 3.75 bla"` то всё работает без проблем

Как решить эту проблему? Я даже не понимаю, куда это гуглить. Язык C#

Comment: а если так попробовать: `string text = "3.14";
IFormatProvider culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
float number = Convert.ToSingle(text, culture);` ошибка будет?

Comment: @Andrew нет, выполнилось успешно

Comment: @Andrew как проблема может быть решена, если код из моего примера всё ещё не работает?)

Comment: попробуйте добавить `IFormatProvider culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");` и конвертируйте учитывая это, либо измените тип данных

Comment: @Andrew о боже, это проблема вызвана культурными различиями с точкой и запятой, т.к. если написать "3,14", то всё работает X_X Пойду винду перенастраивать, спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы, как и я, решили поставить винду на английском языке и столкнулись с такой проблемой, то нужно сделать следующее: Control Panel - Region - Additional settings - Decimal symbol изменить с "," на "."

Comment: каждый раз настраивать OS такое себе решение. Лучше воспользоваться советом Andrew и указывать IFormatProvider